# Django login with rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

While working with the rest framework and frontend native client, I need to log in with both native clients and directly to the API endpoint for development and testing purpose.

Native client login requires token authentication and direct API login requires session authentication. But if I put both in settings.py as default I get csrf error from the native client and if I remove session auth I am not able to login directly to API (I can still log in to the admin console).

My settings .py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
],
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
  'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
)
```

}

What can be done to log in from both for development and testing? Any help?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @DanielGleason I just posted an answer, if that doesn't help you, explain what you are looking for. Now looking back at this question I am not sure what was I asking for :{

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel This is my current setting, check if this helps you -

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    )
}
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)
```